# Dynamically give report viewer a tittle through code

Tags: vb.net

I have two forms StaffTraining and StaffTrainingReport. I would like the title of the report to be from a combobox on the stafftraining form. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to the combobox's TextChanged event that would rename the stafftraining form.

example (stf is the name of the stafftraining form instance)

```
addhandler combobox1.textchanged, sub() stf.text = combobox1.text
```